# pfSense - IPSec through IPSec tunnel possible

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense

I have three sites connected with two IPSec tunnels:

```
Site A - 192.168.10.0/24
        |
    IPSec tunnel
        |
Site B - 192.168.0.0/24
        |
    IPSec tunnel
        |
Site C - 10.0.0.0/8
```

This works great, and I can reach Site A and Site C from Site B. What I need is to reach Site C from Site A. Is that possible with my current setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to negotiate an additional tunnel between Site A and Site C directly, you can do this simply by negotiating the appropriate IPsec policies on the two existing connections (and, of course, allowing forwarding of that traffic on Site B).

Between Site A and B you negotiate `10.0.0.0/8` on Site B and between Site B and Site C you negotiate `192.168.10.0/24` on Site B. This enables Site A and Site C to send traffic to those additional subnets to Site B, which then also can forward that traffic appropriately (it needs forward policies that allow traffic from `192.168.10.0/24` to `10.0.0.0/8` and vice-versa).

If you use IKEv2 you can simply add the additional subnets to Site B's local traffic selector for each of the two connections. And similarly on Site A and Site C for their remote traffic selectors, or you may configure `0.0.0.0/0` there to let Site B do the narrowing to the two subnets.

Comment: Sorry for the silly follow up... By "negotiate `10.0.0.8`", you mean adding another Phase 2?

Comment: No, adding another subnet to the traffic selector of the existing Phase 2/CHILD_SA. (Although, you can obviously add another CHILD_SA, but it's not really necessary.)

Comment: follow up question... I can't add more than one subnet to the traffic selector in the Phase 2... If I add another Phase 2 on Site B, do I need to make changes in Site C (which I don't control)?

Comment: If Site C has the two subnets already in its config with Site B, then no. If not, you either need to add it or add a separate CHILD_SA config too. As I wrote in my answer, with IKEv2 you could also try proposing `0.0.0.0/0` as remote subnet, which Site C can then narrow to the two actual subnets (but it could also redirect any other subnet/address, so be aware of that if you don't control Site C).